# Extracting a special part of a text using RegularExpression

Tags: regex, vba

I want to find a special part of a text using Regular Expressions. For example I have a text like: *KENNFELD TFSWNWRSA 4 4*

I want to extract only *TFSWNWRSA 4 4* from this text and not *KENNFELD* and then I want to

I wrote this code but it returns all total row:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim Name As String
Dim regx As New regexp
Dim matchkennfeld As MatchCollection
Dim matchname As MatchCollection

 Name = "D:/test_DC.txt"
 'Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Name, ForReading)
 Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
  regx.Pattern = "KENNFELD\s+([A-Z 0-9]*)"
  Set matchkennfeld = regx.Execute(ts.ReadLine)
  If matchkennfeld.Count <> 0 Then
     regx.Pattern = "([A-Z 0-9]*)"
    ' MsgBox matchkennfeld.Item(0)
     Set matchname = regx.Execute(matchkennfeld.Item(0))
        For Each Match In matchname
           MsgBox Match
        Next Match
 End If
 Loop
```

would you please help me to do this job?

Comment: You meant something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/qV5jJ5) ?

Comment: but with this I have the complete text I want to have only TFSWNWRSA 4 4

Comment: Please use the `m` modifier.

Comment: From looking at your regex it seems that you are simply getting the contents of a string starting from a known index. Couldn't you simply use the MID function and use the length of "KENNFELD" as the start index? Then trim the result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not good in VB. But I would say matchkennfeld will be an array, which contain the matches along with the group (It is like that in other languages). So when checking `Item(0)` I think its matching with the whole match, not the group. So changing it to check with Sub matches will fix the issue.

`Set matchname = regx.Execute(matchkennfeld(0).SubMatches(0))` may fix the issue.